# How to get instances of inner Spring objects

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

I have a Grails app and need to get access to Spring's instance of the AuthenticationManager/ProviderManager so I can provide it to my instance of RemoteAuthenticationProviderImpl. 
I have the following code in my ApiController.groovy, where I want to authenticate remote clients, which are logging into another Grails app and send back their granted authorities.

```
def remoteAuthentication() {
    def authHeader = request.getHeader('Authorization')
    if (authHeader && apiService.validate(authHeader)) {
        try {
            def remoteAuthenticationManager = new RemoteAuthenticationManagerImpl()
            def response = remoteAuthenticationManager.attemptAuthentication("admin", "password1")
        } catch (Exception) {}
        render response as JSON
    }
    response.status = 401
    render(status: 401, text: 'Failed to authenticate.')
}
```

RemoteAuthenticationManagerImpl is documented [here](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.1.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/rcp/RemoteAuthenticationManagerImpl.html). It can be seen, that I need to provide an AuthenticationManager. I think I need to inject this via a bean, but I can't get that to work.

Comment: `RemoteAuthenticationManager(Impl)` is intended for RPC. It looks misplaced in this context. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Oh ok, thanks. I have one grails app with usernames and passwords and another without them. I am trying to forward login attempts on that server to the other server, so that they can be authenticated. Then it should return the granted authorities and login the user on the server which lacks the credentials.

Comment: The main part I'm struggling with, is how to authenticate a user in my api, given a username and password. Because I don't really have access to the inner workings of Spring, I don't know how to do that, short of implementing the whole process myself. That just doesn't seem like the right way to do it. Do you maybe have an idea, how I can achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem myself. My mistake was, that I put a
`<ref local="authenticationManager" />` instead of `<ref bean="authenticationManager" />` into my resources.xml.